# how to share params between tabs

Tags: android

I have a FragmentActivity with 3 Tabs, they are sharing a Location data (I need latitude and longitude), but I can't get it!

I have this method:

```
  public void addTab(String tag, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {

       tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));


        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        mTabs.put(tag, info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
```

So, when I create the tab:

```
  Bundle bundlePos = new Bundle();
    bundlePos.putString("lat", "98.645");
    bundlePos.putString("lng", "-1.2545");

    mTabManager.addTab("map", mTabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Plano de paradas", this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maps_tab)), maps.class, bundlePos);
```

In maps.java I try to get the lat and lng parameters but I cant.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the the `Bundle` into the `Fragment` using the method [setArguments(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29), and then you have to use `getArguments()` to retrieve it, and through the Bundle you get back from `getArguments()` you can read back `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you, should I do that in the class wich extends Fragment?? 

It has no sense for me, I supposse I should do it in the class wich extends FragmentActivity, could you please tell me more details?

Thank you!

Comment: is info.fragment a fragment instance?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I get it with your help!

It wasn't necesary add setArguments, but, I needed to catch them with getArguments instead of getString as I was trying.

Thanks!!!